# flash/actionscript 3.0 how to logically partition an image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I'm new to `flash` and I'm trying to create a board game with `actionscript 3.0`

I have already created the background (checker squares) for the board and now I have to partition the background by each box. What are the ways I can achieve that? I want to logically put numbers for each square as seen in the picture.

I realized its possible to do it **using lasso tool and convert each to symbols**. But is there any "lazy" way of doing that? There are lots of cuts I'd have to make in order to do that.

[image]

Comment: want to post that image or an idea of that image ? if the symbols have some logic to how they're arranged perhaps you can simply [copyPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels())

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza : Thanks for the response. I added the picture. Please take a look.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza : How is the copyPixels() method come in to help? I didn't understand clearly.

Comment: What do you mean by logically put numbers? Do you want to actually show the numbers on the image or you want to convert a `(x, y)` to integer value? For example, user clicks on `(10, 15)` position of the image and you want to convert `(10, 15)` to `18`?

Comment: @taskinoor : yes. I need to detect which square user clicked and get the according Number. But I don't want the user to see these numbers. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use some simple calculations to map some `(x, y)` value to a number. Lets say:

```
widht = width of the image
height = height of the image
gridCount = 8
gridWidth = width / gridCount
gridHeight = height / gridCount
```

Now first we would like to map user click point `(x, y)` to some integer index `i, j` to the logical 8 x 8 matrix where top left is index `0, 0`.

```
i = x / gridWidth
j = y / gridHeight
```

For example, if `gridWidth = 60`, `gridHeight = 50` and user clicks on `(10, 15)` then `i = 0, j = 0`.

Now we have to map this `i, j` to the specified numbers. As bottom line contains `11, 21, 31, ...` and every column is increasing, the final number will be:

```
num = (11 + i * 10) + (gridCount - j - 1)
```

Converting these equations to AS3 code is straight forward, so I'm not adding them.

Comment: It's quite the answer to my question. Thank you. Finally, I'd like to ask one thing more. I hope to make this grid a 3D one. Then I suspect it will ruin the proportion between each square. Can you please give me a hint to achieve the same results using that 3D graph.

Comment: @shan, basic idea for 3D is same. You have to map `(x, y, z)` to `(i, j, k)` first and then calculate the number from `(i, j, k)`. The exact values will be dependent on how you are populating the 3D grid with numbers, but the idea is same.

Comment: Yeah I see. But when its populating far in to the screen, the size of each individual square will smaller, and will get the shape of a rhombus or a trapezium. you get my idea? I'm not much good with geometry though. :)

Comment: @shan, If the shape is rhombus or trapezium instead of simple cube then this calculation won't work. Sorry, I can't say the equations for rhombus or trapezium without checking the geometry texts :-(. They are not as simple as rectangle/cube equations.

Comment: Its okay. Thank you so much for the hints.